# Matlab functions handles and variable and unknown number of outputs

Tags: matlab, arguments, output, anonymous-function

With an anonymous function, you can return any number of outputs. What I need is to be able to use functors (anonymous functions as arguments of other functions), while not knowing how many outputs I will get.

This is to avoid code duplication by injecting functions calls inside a while loop which is reused in many functions.

Example:

```
function y = foo( x )  
    y = x;
end

function [y1, y2] = goo( x1, x2 )  
    y1 = x1;
    y2 = x2;
end

function [ varargout ] = yolo( functor, varargin )  
    varargout = functor(varargin{:});    
end
```

I want to be able to call:

```
y = yolo(@foo, 2)
[y1, y2] = yolo(@goo, 3, 4);
```

Is there any way to achieve this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to get the number of outputs of an anonymous function (a function handle to an inline function) because the output is always `varargout` and therefore `nargout` is always going to return `-1`

```
myfunc = @(x, y) x + y;
nargout(myfunc)
%   -1
```

However, it looks like you don't have anonymous functions, but rather just function handles to normal functions that are defined in an `.m` file and have an explicit number of output arguments. In this case, you can combine `nargout` with `{:}` indexing to fill `varargout` with all of the output arguments.

```
function y = foo(x)
    y = x;
end

function [y1, y2] = goo(x1, x2)
    y1 = x1;
    y2 = x2;
end

function varargout = yolo(functor, varargin)
    [varargout{1:nargout(functor)}] = functor(varargin{:});
end

y = yolo(@foo, 2)
[y1, y2] = yolo(@goo, 3, 4)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was trying to look for a workaround using the number of outputs as an argument but it seems this will work, going to check this right now.

I did not know I could use nargout as a function